# Linear gradient for background image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I am getting an error with this code:

```
var sectionStyle = {
  paddingTop:"2%",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ") , linearGradient(#eb01a5, #d13531)"
}
```

The error is:

> parsing error Failed to compile. ./src/App.js Line 203: Parsing error: Unexpected token 201 | width: "100%", 202 | height: "100%", > 203 | backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")" , linearGradient(#eb01a5, #d13531'); | ^ 204 | } 205 | 206 |

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:` type `=`

try this

```
var sectionStyle = {
  paddingTop = "2%",
  width = "100%",
  height = "100%",
  backgroundImage = "url(" + Background + ") , linearGradient(#eb01a5, #d13531)"
}
```